# Javascript replace regex all html tags except p,a and img

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to remove all html tags except `p`, `a` and `img` tags. Right now I have:

```
content.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
```

But this removes all HTML tags.

This are examples of the content of the api:

```
    <table id="content_LETTER.BLOCK9" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#F7EBF5">
<tbody><tr><td class="ArticlePadding" colspan="1" rowspan="1" align="left" valign="top"><div>what is the opposite of...[] rest of text
```

Comment: You can go two ways, either fix your pattern to not match those tags or change your replace from an empty string to a function that checks the tag and returns the match if you want to keep it or an empty string if not.

Comment: add sample input - desired output - current output ...

Comment: Its for an app that's load WordPress data from a post with a lot of styling but that's undesirable for the app.

Comment: You can still make a simple example input/output without having tons of formatting. Even something as simple as `<b>remove these</b><p>keep these</p>` would be fine.

Comment: for example: `<table id="content_LETTER.BLOCK9" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#F7EBF5">↵<tbody>↵<tr>↵<td class="ArticlePadding" colspan="1" rowspan="1" align="left" valign="top">↵<div>what is the opposite of... rest of text`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may match the tags to keep in a capture group and then, using alternation, all other tags. Then replace with `$1`:

```
(<\/?(?:a|p|img)[^>]*>)|<[^>]+>
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Sm4Azv/2

And the JavaScript demo:

```js
var input = 'b<body>b a<a>a h1<h1>h1 p<p>p p</p>p img<img />img';
var output = input.replace(/(<\/?(?:a|p|img)[^>]*>)|<[^>]+>/ig, '$1');
console.log(output);
```

Comment: This would also omit <pre></pre> or any other tag which starts with a, p or img

Answer (score 7):

You can use the below regex to *remove all HTML tags except* `a`, `p` and `img`:

```
<\/?(?!a)(?!p)(?!img)\w*\b[^>]*>
```

Replace with an empty string.

```js
var text = '<tr><p><img src="url" /> some text <img another></img><div><a>blablabla</a></div></p></tr>';
var output = text.replace(/<\/?(?!a)(?!p)(?!img)\w*\b[^>]*>/ig, '');
console.log(output);
```

[Regex 101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/B0K4zm/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = 'b<p on>b <p>good p</p> a<a>a h1<h1>h1 p<pre>p p</p onl>p img<img src/>img';
var output = input.replace(/(<(?!\/?((a|img)(\s+[^>]+)*|p)\s*>)([^>]+)>)/ig, '');
console.log(output);
output: bb <p>good p</p> a<a>a h1h1 pp pp img<img src/>img
```

And if you'd like to remove JS event handler attributes:

```
var input = 'b<p on>b <p>good p</p> a<a>a h1<h1>h1 p<pre>p p</p onl>p img<img src="y.gif" /> see <img src="x.png" onerror alt="cat" /> there';
var output = input.replace(/(<(?!\/?((a|img)(\s+((?!on)[^>])+)*|p)\s*>)([^>]+)>)/ig, '');
console.log(output);
output: bb <p>good p</p> a<a>a h1h1 pp pp img<img src="y.gif" /> see  there
```